# image preview before upload file to server in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-data

```
$.ajax({
            url: "index2.php?id=upload",
            data:  new FormData($("#form")[0]),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            beforeSend : function()
            {
                // how can I get src of image/size and its name?
            },
            success: function(data)
            {  
                ....
            },
```

in top code,how can I get src,size,name and mime type of file via jQuery in beforeSend function?

---

Not duplicated!
it's not work for file type array

Comment: Not duplicated! it's not work for file type array

Comment: What are you trying to preview? How is it not an image like in the duplicate question? What array are you talking about?